# java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory: Provider com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory not a subtype

Tags: weblogic12c

I am using Weblogic 12c. I m trying to deploy myApplication.war in Weblogic.
While deploying i get bellow error.

```
An error occurred during activation of changes, please see the log for details.
Message icon - Error java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory: Provider com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory not a subtype
Message icon - Error javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory: Provider com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory not a subtype
```

The same myApplication.war I am able to deploy in weblogic-10,Jboss and Tomcat. But not in weblgic-12c.

I googled and found that i need to include dependency for `xercesImpl.jar`. I included that but, That dint help. still I am facing the same issue.

I tried including some other dependency, those are.

```html
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.woodstox</groupId>
            <artifactId>woodstox-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
            <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.1</version>
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
            <artifactId>stax2-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
            <artifactId>woodstox-core-lgpl</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

the above dependency dint help. Any suggestion for trouble shooting the application,any link.

> It seems to be very common problem with weblogic-12c. what is root
>   cause of the exception?

Comment: Hi, did you resolve this ?, i having the same issue ...

Comment: It was a jar conflict, make sure you are providing the correct implementation class for XMLInputFactory.

Comment: which correct implementation resolved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I add only one dependency in ear pom.xml. It's work for me in WLS 12.2.1.3.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.woodstox</groupId>
        <artifactId>woodstox-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and another libs was exclude, such as org.codehaus.woodstox, stax-api

Answer (score 0):

In WebLogic.xml add:

```
<container-descriptor>
    <prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>
</container-descriptor>
```