# Stax Provider Subtype issue - Tomcat

Tags: java, dependencies, classloader, stax

I am having a portlet deployed on Liferay which has webservice call and is using internally axis libraries. When a webservice is called I am getting following error

Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory: Provider com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory not a subtype

I checked various other posts

- [java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory: Provider com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory not a subtype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42153342/java-util-serviceconfigurationerror-javax-xml-stream-xmlinputfactory-provider)
- List item

I analyzed the error line in breaking it up into two parts

1. Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory
2. Provider com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory not a subtype

And came to conclusion that the error is due to Stax Implementation mismatch.

So I check the lib directory and found the following jars
[image]

I see that WstxInputFactory is present in woodstox-core-asl-4.1.4

To see from where this jar gets added I checked the build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://cdn.lfrs.sl/repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.gradle.plugins.css.builder", version: "2.0.0"
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.liferay.css.builder"

dependencies {

    def withoutServletAPI = { 
        exclude group: 'javax.servlet', module: 'servlet-api'  
    }

    compile group: "org.springframework", name: "spring-webmvc-portlet", version: "4.1.5.RELEASE"

    compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.portal.kernel", version: "2.6.0"
    compileOnly group: "javax.portlet", name: "portlet-api", version: "2.0"
    compileOnly group: "javax.servlet", name: "javax.servlet-api", version: "3.0.1"
    compileOnly group: "org.osgi", name: "org.osgi.service.component.annotations", version: "1.3.0"

    compile group: "org.apache.axis", name:"axis", version: "1.4"
    compile group: "org.apache.axis2", name:"axis2-adb", version: "1.6.3", withoutServletAPI
    compile group: "org.apache.axis2", name:"axis2-transport-local", version: "1.6.3", withoutServletAPI
    compile group: "org.apache.axis2", name:"axis2-transport-http", version: "1.6.3", withoutServletAPI
    compile group: "com.google.code.gson", name:"gson", version: "2.3.1"    
    compile group: "jstl", name:"jstl", version: "1.2"
    compile group: "taglibs", name:"standard", version: "1.1.2"

    //compile group: "memberservice", name:"memberservice", version: "1.0.0"


    compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.util.java", version: "2.4.0"

    //compile group: "com.sun.xml.ws", name: "jaxws-rt", version: "2.2.10"

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.8.1'
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-all', version: '1.9.5'

    compile files('../../modules/memberservice/build/libs/memberservice-1.0.0.jar')

}

war {
    dependsOn buildCSS
    exclude "**/*.scss"

    filesMatching("**/.sass-cache/") {
        it.path = it.path.replace(".sass-cache/", "")
    }

    includeEmptyDirs = false
}
```

I checked the dependency tree in gradle and found that woodstox-core-asl-4.1.4 is a transitive dependency for axis2-adb-1.6.3 which is in build.gradle.

Obviously there is some conflict in jar which is causing the above error but I am not able to find which jar is causing it. My suspicion is that JDK 8 already has XMLInputFactory and in my war I see that there is geronimo-stax-api which again is a transitive dependency and that might be causing conflict.

I am looking for what is actually causing the issue.

Note: This code is not created by me. My client has given this code which was running on older version of Liferay(6.2) on JBoss and created by different vendor and we are moving to the newer version of Liferay(DXP) on Tomcat.

PS: I also checked Tomcat's lib directory and there is no stax implementation there too

Answer (score -1):

```
I have a similar issue. When upgraded portlet is deployed, spring application boots up successfully. When attempted to view a portlet page, this error occurs. 

2018-08-29 14:31:50.955 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-8][render_portlet_jsp:131] null
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not a subtype
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:376)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder$1.run(FactoryFinder.java:294)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:289)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:267)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAXParserFactory.java:127)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlBaseTLV.validate(JstlBaseTLV.java:194)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV.validate(JstlCoreTLV.java:138)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.validate(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:957)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateXmlView(Validator.java:1929)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validate(Validator.java:1896)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:223)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:451)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:625)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
```

Comment: Try to edit original question to bump it, but don't answer it if you have the same problem.